# Can I recover funds where the wrong destination tag was used while transferring ripple to bittrex?

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways, bittrex

Is a refund possible if i entered the wrong Destination tag and the right address while transferring XRP to my bittrex wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Bittrex *immediately*. They may be able to return the funds if the destination address doesn't map to a valid customer. But if it does, they probably already credited that customer and there is likely nothing that they can do.

Comment: Ripple asks for a destination tag and an address while transferring it, i entered the right address and the wrong destination tag. I contacted them they said they might be able to give it back in 30 days

Comment: @Sumit: in the end did you get your ripples back? I just did the same mistake now, sending from bitstamp to cex.io (address correct, just the tag I mistakenly inverted a digit with another: 32140 instead of 31240). I contacted the supported and also tweeted them, I really hope it's gonna work, after all an exchange is regulated, and ripple centralized. This is very similar to a banking scenario and in such cases a refund should be possible.

Comment: @firepol yeah i got them back in 15 days